# Как создать тип и использовать?

Tags: javascript, ооп, angular2

В [официальном гайде](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#hero-object) angular2 для сущности Hero рекомендуется использовать пользовательский тип для данных:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Я написал подобный простейший [проект](https://github.com/zlodiak/ng4_agenda), но без использования такого типа. Помогите пожалуйста понять:

1. как его использовать **в моём проекте**
2. зачем нужно это делать, в чём заключается хотя бы небольшой плюс
   использования такого подхода

В общих чертах, в моём проекте происходит следующее. Есть набор данных в json-файле. Сервис их считывает, а компонент выводит в виде расписания при помощи материал вкладок(MatTabs)

Вот фрагмент json:

```
},
"dd0b8a4a-9675-4d16-94cc-0b23bd3f3256": {
    "date": "2",
    "start": "09:30 ",
    "end": " 10:10",
    "title": "Rosulip, маркетинговая стратегия",
    "place": "Зал Премьер 3",
    "order": "220"
},
"4820f069-d56f-41d9-902a-078d4b6c8855": {
    "start": "10:10 ",
    "end": " 10:30",
    "title": "Rosulip, SMART-визит",
    "place": "Зал Премьер 3",
    "order": "230",
    "date": "2"
},
```

Сервис:

```
  getAgenda(): Observable<any> {
    let result = this.http.get('../assets/json/agenda.json');
    return result;
  }
```

Компонент:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private agendaObj: any[] = [];
    private agenda: any[] = [];
    private dates: string[] = [];

  constructor(private agendaService: AgendaService) { };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getAgenda();
    }  

  private getAgenda(): void {
    this.agendaService
        .getAgenda()
        .subscribe(data => {     
                                let response = JSON.parse(data._body);
                                //console.log(response); 

                                this.dates = response['headers'].date.options;                                                                                   
                    console.log(this.dates);                                                         

                                        this.agendaObj = response.values;
                                        //console.log(this.agendaObj);  

                    let this_ = this;
                                        Object.keys(this.agendaObj).map(function(val, key) {
                                          this_.agenda.push({
                                            date: +this_.agendaObj[val].date,
                                            start: this_.agendaObj[val].start,
                                            end: this_.agendaObj[val].end,                                          
                                            title: this_.agendaObj[val].title,
                                            place: this_.agendaObj[val].place,
                                            order: +this_.agendaObj[val].order
                                          });
                                        });  
                                        console.log(this.agenda)                                                                     
                  }, 
                  err => {
                    console.log('err')         
                  });    
  };   

}
```

Как видите, я обхожусь без использования пользовательского типа, описанного в гайде. При это всё работает без проблем. Но хотелось бы разобраться в тех двух вопросах, которые я озвучил выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как его использовать

Так же, как обычно используются классы в языках программирования:

- Можно создать экземпляр класса

  ```
  let hero = new Hero();
  ```
- Можно изменять свойства экзмепляра

  ```
  hero.id = 7;
  hero.name += '_great';
  ```
- Можно добавить в класс методы и вызывать их:

  ```
  export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    isHeroGreat(): boolean {
      return this.name.includes('great');
    }
  }

  let hero = new Hero();
  hero.name = 'great_hero';

  // где-нибудь в другом месте
  if (hero.isGreat()) {
    ...
  }
  ```

> зачем нужно это делать, в чём заключается хотя бы небольшой плюс использования такого подхода

Основное преимущество заключается в статической проверке типов во время компиляции (код для angular'а пишется на языке TypeScript, потом этот код компилируется в JavaScript). То есть во время компиляции, если вы используете типы (то есть ваши объекты создаются с помощью конструкторов, а не через `let hero = {}`) и вы указываете типы полей и возвращаемых значений функций (не `any`) будут произведены следующие проверки:

- Все присваивания происходят с учётом типа. То есть нельзя присвоить переменной типа `Hero` значение переменной типа `Book`
- Обращение к полям тоже проверяется: если вы нечаянно напишите `hero.namr` вместо `hero.name`, то компилятор это заметит

Также имеются плюсы в виде автодополнения в IDE.

Comment: Понятно. Конкретно в моём проекте можно такой подход не использовать и оставить всё как есть потому что я просто получаю данные и ничего с ними не делаю. Но если бы, например, я добавил бы возможность создавать пункты в этом расписании, то мне пришлось бы использовать оператор new и затем инициализировать созданный объект(чтобы в итоге добавить его в расписание). и в этом случае при инициализации я мог бы вместо ключа time написать ключ timr. Правильно я понял ваш ответ?..

Comment: @cyklop77 такой подход можно в любом проекте не использовать. Но, имхо, лучше в любом проекте такой подход использовать. Предложение `при инициализации я мог бы вместо ключа time написать ключ timr` я не очень понял, поясните подробней, пожалуйста. Если что, инициализацию через `new` можно сделать очень просто: `let hero = Object.assign(new Hero(), heroJson)`, где `heroJson` это обычный javascript объект (сейчас вы с такими работаете)

Comment: Вот тут я набросал пример, в котором мог бы допустить ошибку time-timr: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734213/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2