# Почему нельзя пушить в неинициализированный массив?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему нельзя сделать пуш в следующей ситуации.

Я объявил пользовательский тип данных:

```
export class AgendaLine {
    order: number;
    title: string;
    title_en: string;
    subtitle: string;
    subtitle_en: string;
    location: string;
    location_en: string;
    date: number;
    time: string;
    icon: string;
}
```

Затем импортировал его в компонент и объявил переменную компонента:

```
import { AgendaLine } from '../agenda-line';
...
private agenda: AgendaLine[];
.....
```

Затем пытаюсь в него пушить так:

```
Object.keys(this.agendaObj).map(function(key, val) {
    let line = new AgendaLine();

    line['order'] = +this_.agendaObj[key].order;
    line['title'] = this_.agendaObj[key].title;
    line['title_en'] = this_.agendaObj[key].title_en;
    line['subtitle'] = this_.agendaObj[key].subtitle;
    line['subtitle_en'] = this_.agendaObj[key].subtitle_en;
    line['location'] = this_.agendaObj[key].location;
    line['location_en'] = this_.agendaObj[key].location_en;
    line['date'] = +this_.agendaObj[key].date;
    line['time'] = this_.agendaObj[key].time;
    line['icon'] = this_.agendaObj[key].icon;

    console.log(line);

    this_.agenda.push(line);                                            
});
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Проблема решается если в компоненте объявить переменную так:

```
private agenda: AgendaLine[] = [];
```

Но всё равно ход событий непонятен. В первом случае я же объявил переменную вполне конкретного типа. Что же ещё нужно ангуляру/тайпскрипту?

Comment: Если будете писать `line['order'] = ...`, то никакой проверки типов при компиляции не будет. Лучше писать `line.order = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тип и значение переменной это совершенно разные вещи, особенно в TypeScript, где типы, во-первых, не обязательны, а, во-вторых, после трансляции TS в JS типы полностью исчезают из кода и, соответственно JS ничего не знает что вы там объявили за тип (потому что JS нетипизированный язык и типы не понимает). В итоге переменная получается не инициализирована (а значит равна `undefined`) и вы пытаетесь у `undefined`вызвать метод `push`, которого у него нет, на что и получаете вполне обоснованную ошибку.

Поэтому всегда инициализируйте все переменные, если есть такая возможность.